# While converting the circle or ellipse element to the image using the RenderTargetBitmap gets blank image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, rendertargetbitmap

Description:

- Need to save the specific circular portion of the image using the RenderTargetBitmap gets blank image.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Load the image control with the image.
2. Save the image source to the image brush source.
3. Set the image brush to the ellipse fill.
4. Then convert the ellipse element to image using the RenderTargetBitmap.

(OR)

1. Run the below sample:
2. Click the crop button to crop the image.
3. Click the set source button to set the element converted image to the image source.
4. Output gets a blank image.

Sample Link:
https://github.com/ragulsv/CircleCrop